# Как в теге Input можно создать вот такой календарь

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, html5

Здравствуйте! Как в теге Input можно создать вот такого вида календарь (см. на рисунок), где можно выбрать время и дату, чтоб в дальнейшем записать данные в БД.

[image: число, месяц, год, день недели и время]

Comment: Создать можно используя `HTML+CSS+JS`. Подробно вряд ли кто опишет, ведь создание этого макета вполне пойдёт как заказ на фриланс-бирже.

Comment: Поищи готовые плагины

Answer (score 4):

Это доработка Таймпикера http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ , называется DateTimePicker (вот похожая модификация, нужно только стили поправить http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ ).

Answer (score 2):

В спецификации HTML 5 появился встроенный календарь `<input type="date">`
http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/kalendar

Comment: Только при использовании html5 <input type="date" /> будьте готовы, что работать будет далеко не кроссбраузерно. На пример в firefox - вообще не работает.
http://caniuse.com/#search=date